# Use CRM 2011 sdk in Sharepoint SDK

Tags: sharepoint, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, dynamics-crm

Since the CRM 2011 utilises .NET 4 and SharePoint is on .NET 3.5 I started two different projects CRM 2011 Connector and SharePoint 2010 BDC project for it.

When I add this library as reference I get warnings about .NET framework versions.

How to make interaction more clear between .Net 3.5 and .Net 4?
Is it possible to achieve the goal using WCF for CRM and SharePoint SDKs?

Sultan

Comment: @Basant B. Pandey I've deployed a WCF application with some custom data providers on my entities on the CRM to supply BDC list for SharePoint external list